# How to prevent insertion point from changing its position in an input element when pressing arrows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have an auto-complete box where user can choose between results with arrow keys while the `input` element is in focus. when the user uses up and down arrows, the insertion point jumps between the start and the end of the text. How can I prevent this from happening? I tried the following but it does not work:

```
    $("#Hdr_nav_search_input").keypress(function(event){
        if(event.which==38 || event.which==40){
                event.preventDefault();     
        }
    })
```

Comment: You need to *call* the `preventDefault` method. Add `()` behind it.

Comment: It is still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#Hdr_nav_search_input").keydown(function(e){
   if(e.which==38 || e.which==40){
            e.preventDefault();     
    }
});
```

Try the above code. You are handling the event very late. To prevent the default behavior, you need to handle the `KeyDown` event and special keys don't trigger `keypress` in the first place as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Use keydown event instead of key press.